# Android Studioで「Gradle Project sync failed」とエラーが出てしまいます

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio（バージョンは最新のFlamingoです）をインストールし、
新しくプロジェクトを作成したところ、最初のビルドがうまくいかず、下記のようなエラーが表示されます。
エラー文で検索をしてみたのですが、解決方法がみつからず困っています。
どのように対応すればよいのでしょうか？

```
Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android', version: '1.8.20', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android', version: '1.8.20', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android:org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.gradle.plugin:1.8.20')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Google
    MavenRepo
```

エラーとあわせて表示されたbuild.gradleファイルの内容は次のようになっています。

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.20' apply false
}
```

エラーが表示された際のAndroid studioのキャプチャを掲載します。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

以下の手順でどうでしょうか。

1. Tools→Markdown Converter→Configure Pandoc…を選択
2. Build,Execution,Deployment→Build Tools→Gradleを選択しGradle JDKの▼をクリック
3. jbr-17 JetBrains Runtime version 17.0.6を選択
4. ApplyをクリックしてOKをクリック
5. Try Againをクリック

以下の記事で詳しく書いています。

[【Android Studio】Flamingoで新しいプロジェクトがエラーになるとき](https://everydayisagoodday.hatenadiary.com/entry/2023/07/07/101145)